# Чи є відповідник до слова "арбітраж"?

Tags: іменники, іншомовні-слова

Натрапила на cтаттю [Міжнародний арбітраж та Україна: що потрібно для виконання рішень](https://mind.ua/openmind/20181059-mizhnarodnij-arbitrazh-ta-ukrayina-shcho-potribno-dlya-vikonannya-rishen), в якій часто використовується слово **"арбітраж"**, зокрема введене і в словосполучення **"арбітражні рішення"**, **"звернутися в арбітраж"** та ін.

Отож цікавить, чи є відповідник до цього слова?

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/arbitrazh) подають лише саму семантику слова.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Згідно з [офіційним сайтом української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/a/arbitrazh/22-1-0-713) синонімом до слова *арбітраж* є *суд*, те саме [в словнику синонімів](https://%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B8.%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80/%D0%90/%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6).

Крім того, якщо ми розглянемо слово *арбітр* (людина, яка вирішує арбітражні питання), побачимо, що відповідником може бути *[суддя](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/arbitr)* або, якщо бути точнішим, *третейський суддя* (згідно з [Вікіпедією](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4) синонімом до *арбітражний суд* може бути *третейський суд*, тобто недержавний). Також врахуйте, що арбітражні суди в Україні називаються *господарські суди*, бо в Україні арбітражні суди з 2001 року перейменовані на господарські.

Отож, найкращим відповідником будуть *третейський суд* або *господарський суд*, тобто: *звернутися в арбітраж* — *звернутися в господарський суд*.

Answer (score 3):

Так розумію, потрібен відповідник українського походження.

[Словник чужомовних слів Павла Штепи](https://ia902801.us.archive.org/8/items/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt)

> **арбітр** — суддя, розсудник, посередник
>   **арбітраж** — суд, посередництво